# Firebase Push Notifications on click action in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have fully working app with Firebase PUSH Notifications implemented. What I am trying to do is when the user taps on the notification received, the app should be opened and then UIAlert should be displayed containing title and the body of the push notification that was received.

Here is how I send my notifications:

```
$headers = array(
        "Authorization: key=$key",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $notification = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
        'sound' => 'default'
    );

    $apns = array(
        'headers'=> $apns_headers = array(
            'apns-priority' => '5'
        )
    );

    $message = array(
        'registration_ids' => $tokens,
        'notification' => $notification,
        'apns' => $apns,
        'time_to_live' => $ttl,
        'content_available' => true,
        'delay_while_idle' => false
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: So, do you want to know how to display the title and the body message from notification tap on UIAlert inside the application?

Comment: Please clarify your question, Which side you want to know? Do you want to know how to implement Alerts in iOS? Or how to handle notifications on the iPhone platform?